# Also check realloc() if shrinking allocated size of memory?

Tags: c++, c, realloc

When you call `realloc()` you should check whether the function failed before assigning the returned pointer to the pointer passed as a parameter to the function...

I've always followed this rule.

Now is it necessary to follow this rule when you know for sure the memory will be truncated and not increased?

I've never ever seen it fail. Just wondered if I could save a couple instructions.

Comment: Consider this, what if the implementation found that your smaller allocation could reside elsewhere in memory? (especially when the memory is somewhat fragmented) The implementation isn't required to return the same memory location in such a case.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I don't see what's the relation between the asked question and your comment. The question is could the realloc() operation fail in such context.

Comment: @martinkunev: The question is asking if it is necessary to test if a `realloc()` call that would make a block smaller should be tested at all. The answer is yes absolutely. The implementation may at its discretion attempt to allocate a new block and move the items to that block. That new allocation may fail so therefore must be checked. The last bit of my comment was pointing out on any chance that assuming a shrinking operation will always return the same block would be incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`realloc` may, at its discretion, copy the block to a new address regardless of whether the new size is larger or smaller. This may be necessary if the `malloc` implementation requires a new allocation to "shrink" a memory block (e.g. if the new size requires placing the memory block in a different allocation pool). This is noted in the [`glibc` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Changing-Block-Size.html):

> In several allocation implementations, making a block smaller sometimes necessitates copying it, so it can fail if no other space is available.

Therefore, you must *always* check the result of `realloc`, even when shrinking. It is possible that `realloc` has failed to shrink the block because it cannot simultaneously allocate a new, smaller block.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you `realloc` (read carefully [realloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) and about Posix [realloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/realloc.html) please) to a smaller size, the underlying implementation is doing the equivalent of `malloc` (of the new smaller size), followed by a `memcpy` (from old to new zone), then `free` (of the old zone). Or it may do nothing... (e.g. because some crude `malloc` implementations maitain a limited set of sizes -like power of two or 3 times power of two-, and the old and new size requirements fits in the same size....)

That `malloc` can fail. So `realloc` can still fail.

Actually, I usually don't recommend using `realloc` for that reason: just do the `malloc`, `memcpy`, `free`   yourself.

Indeed, dynamic heap memory functions like `malloc` rarely fail. But when they do, chaos may happen if you don't handle that. On Linux and some other Posix systems you could [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_AS` -e.g. using bash `ulimit` builtin- to lower the limits for testing purposes.

You might want to study the source code implementations of [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management). For example [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) (for Linux) is very readable code. On Linux, `malloc` is often built above [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (the C library may allocate a large chunk of memory using `mmap` then managing smaller used and freed memory zones inside it).

Comment: How does it maintain the same memory address if it's allocating then freeing the old?

Comment: It does not maintain the same memory address in general.

Comment: By the way, I recommend looking at POSIX documentation for `realloc`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/realloc.html